# Compare image width to number fails

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

This script fails at the if statement with "Error: ( : 1) >: argument 2 must be: number", why?

```
(define x 1500)

(if(> x (gimp-image-width image))
(set! x (gimp-image-width image))
)
```

Is there any good reference on version of Scheme used in GIMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try it in the script-fu console `gimp-image-width` returns a list and not a number:

```
(gimp-image-width 1)
(400)
```

So you have to extract the element of the list:

```
(define x 1500)
(if(> x (car (gimp-image-width 1)))
(set! x (gimp-image-width 1))
)
```

As a side note, if you are starting writing Gimp scripts, use Python, it is much easier:

```
width=min(1500,image.width)
```